# Split string and use last value?

Tags: apache-pig

I would like to split a string fields into parts (space separator) and use the last value of a field. I know i can split data using strsplit, but how i can take the last value?

eg: **input:**

```
AAA BB CC

SS DD

AA
```

**output:**

```
CC

DD

AA
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with a combination of [LAST INDEX_OF](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#last-index-of), [SUBSTRING](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#substring) and [SIZE](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#size).

Comment: thanks, i have just done it with LAST INDEX_OF, SUBSTRING i missed the length function but i used 1000 es end of substring, i guess size doing the same like length in sql

Answer (score 2):

input

```
AAA BB CC
SS DD
AA

A = load 'input.txt' as (line : chararray);
B = FOREACH A generate line, LAST_INDEX_OF(line,' ') AS ind;  
C = FOREACH B GENERATE (ind>0?SUBSTRING(line,ind+1,ind+3):SUBSTRING(line,0,2)); 
Dump C;
```

output

```
(CC)
(DD)
(AA)
```

if last value size is not same in this case use size() instead of ind+3

Answer (score 1):

One more solution. It works well for all combination.

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' AS line;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT(line,'\\s*(\\w+)$',1);
DUMP B;
```

**Output:**

```
(CC)
(DD)
(AA)
```